# Searching for "|" in the users page summons a lolcat

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, users

Go to the users page and type a | in the "Type to find users" box. After a second or two a friendly lolcat will appear to work on your problem.

Comment: Same behavior with `"`

Comment: I have no idea why you're doing this, @Jon, but keep going.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of problems with that text field

Comment: In before `status-bydesign`.

Comment: I was about to say that maybe the cat is the only SO user with a "|" in its name, but I see no "|" in ["Zoe"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/workin-on-ur-problemz/).

Comment: So, what do you have to do to summon a [trollcat](http://trollcats.com/)?

Comment: You say bug, I say *feature!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that if a `|` or `"` appears anywhere in the URL before the query we also have an lolcat.

- https://stackoverflow.com/|
- https://stackoverflow.com/%22
- https://stackoverflow.com/workin-on-ur-prob|emz

This is reflected in the user search box because the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/users/filter/<nameToSearch>?_=(numbers)` is fetched.

The “actual error” from the pages' comment is

```
<!--
Actual error:
Illegal characters in path.
-->
```

Comment: so MVC routing bug?